# Ground state of spin in magnetic field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-spin

I am trying to solve a time dependent perturbation theory problem, and it involves the Hamiltonian
$$H=-\mu B\sigma_z$$
And a perturbation
$$V=-\mu B_1\sigma\cdot(\cos(\omega t)\hat x-\sin(\omega t)\hat y)$$
I want to find the probability that the spin will go from the Ground state of $H_0$ at t=0 to the excited state at time t.

I understand the perturbation theory, I just need to figure out the initial and final states.  I thought there were two ground states (either up or down).  So what are the excited state and the final state?

Comment: notice that your first line tells you that in the unperturbed system, the spin up eigenstate has less energy than the spin down eigenstate.

Comment: So in other words, it wants to know the probability that it goes from spin up to spin down?

Comment: Ground state means lowest energy state. There are two eigenstates of the unperturbed Hamiltonian. One of these has a lower energy, and one of these has a higher energy. The lower energy state is the ground state, the higher energy state is the excited state.